# htaccess rewrite rule not working for jsp files, all remaining files(.html,js,css,jpg) are working fine?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, jsp, mod-rewrite

I have hosted jsp website in linux server in following folder structure:

```
public_html/ROOT/hosted_files_including_jsp_and_other_files
public_html/.htaccess
```

I have added the following rewrite rule in htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?my_domain\.com$
RewriteRule !^ROOT/ /ROOT%{REQUEST_URI}  [L]
```

Its rewriting every url for files like html, js, css and images. But when I try to call jsp files its not rewriting and showing 404 file not found error.

ie. When I call:

```
https://www.my_domain.com/test.html
```

it's redirecting to `https://www.my_domain.com/ROOT/test.html`

But when I call:

```
https://www.my_domain.com/test.jsp
```

It's not redirecting and showing 404 file not found error

Comment: The linux server running shared tomcat 5.5, and the jsp files are running fine if we call directly. But I have to rewrite the jsp files urls to /ROOT/ directory. Could you please help me to solve the issue ?

Comment: How is Apache communicating with Tomcat? Is there AJP connector in place?

Comment: Actually, I cant get such details from the hosted shared server. I have only know the version is used Apache Tomcat/5.5.36. And here our jsp scripts are working fine with the url having "/ROOT/". And the rewrite process also working fine the urls except ".jsp" extension. I think there are some issue with .jsp files with htaccess mod rewrite. Could you please help to solve the issue.

Comment: Most likely .htaccess is not even used for `.jsp` files

Comment: Then, is there any alternate way for redirect jsp files to subdirectory (/ROOT/)  ?

Answer (score 0):

Apache server does not run JSP by itself, it requires a servlet engine to be plugged in. Try the Jakarta-Tomcat engine, also supported by Apache.

Comment: Thank you for you sudden reply. Actually, I can run https://www.my_domain.com/ROOT/test.jsp, jsp is working there, but I want to redirect https://www.my_domain.com/test.jsp to https://www.my_domain.com/ROOT/test.jsp. So the mod_rewrite is not working here

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ROOT/$1 [R,NE,QSA,P,L]   ?

Comment: I have try the given rewrite rule, but again not working for jsp files remaining files are working fine. ?

Comment: You could log what happens

Comment: RewriteLog "logs/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9

in your httpd.conf

Comment: Actually, I cant access for the httpd.conf file as my site hosted in a shared server.